# syntax error C2061 using structs

Tags: c, struct

Got a bit confused about this error I'm getting ...

So, in this code snippet, I have 2 structs :

```
typedef struct 
{
    char  *cMake;   
    model *testModel;
} make;

typedef struct 
{
    char * cModel;    
} model;
```

Now, if I compile, I receive the following errors :

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'model'  
Error   2   error C2059: syntax error : '}'
```

If I comment the `model *testModel` line, it compiles fine ... Any ideeas ? Thank you !

Comment: Listing a compiler error number says nothing unless you also mention which compiler that is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `model` type before `make`:

```
typedef struct 
{
    char * cModel;    
} model;

typedef struct 
{
    char  *cMake;   
    model *testModel;
} make;
```

Generally an identifier name cannot be used before it has been fully declared.

Answer (score 1):

order!

```
typedef struct 
{
    char * cModel;    
} model;

typedef struct 
{
    char  *cMake;   
    model *testModel;
} make;
```

your compiler doesn't know model when you use it, because it's defined later in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare `model` before tring to use it. The simplest way to do that in this case is to simply swap the two definitions around.

You could also forward declare `model` and leave the order the same but that's unnecessary here.

Comment: It worked, now I realise it too ... sorry for wasting your time :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you define model first, it works well.

```
   typedef struct
{
    char * cModel;
} model;

typedef struct
{
    char  *cMake;
    model *testModel;
} make;
```